# EditText doesn't show cursor or soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make a simple Hello World app with an EditText, but the EditText shows neither a cursor nor a soft keyboard when I click it. There is no way to enter any text. I am getting the same problem in both the emulator and on my Galaxy Nexus device.

Here is my activity_main.xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
        android:inputType="text"  >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't have anything special in my Activity's OnCreate() method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: remove the transparent background, and set ems

Comment: Removing the transparent background line did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The OP had the following solution as an edit inside the question (and I'm just moving it to the proper place, [as expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278050/editing-self-answer-out-of-question)):

---

Removing the line

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

as suggested by [meh's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411957/edittext-doesnt-show-cursor-or-soft-keyboard#comment-27046592) fixed the problem.